# How to dynamically schedule and cancel node-schedule event?

Tags: node.js

```
const schedule = require("node-schedule");

let x = schedule.scheduleJob("*/2 * * * *", () => {
  console.log("hi its a scheduled message");
});

x.cancel();
```

This way we can schedule and cancel a job in node js. But how can it be done dynamically?

Comment: what do you mean by dynamic ? when do you want your job to be scheduled and on what bases so you want to cancel it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below syntax for dynamic schedule of job and settimeout for keeping some time interval for schedule cancel.

```
const schedule = require("node-schedule");

let time = 1;

let x = schedule.scheduleJob('*/'+time+' * * * *', () => { 
  console.log("hi its a scheduled message");
});

let cancel_time = 100000;

setTimeout(() => {
  x.cancel();
}, cancel_time);    //after 100 second
```